# Spring Boot test with Repository can not disable org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Today I started a spring boot project of Gradle:

`springBootVersion = '1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'`

But when write Unittest for repository I got an error because of loading data.

I have already had `schema.sql` and `import.sql` in `test/resources` directory, and Spring boot init with these script.

But it seems that Hibernate try to re-create by running `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export`.

I've try to configure with some hibernates properties but It doesn't work.

```
    2016-08-11 19:28:41.675  INFO 30221 --- [           main] c.d.a.h.repository.FooRepositoryTest   : The following profiles are active: test
    2016-08-11 19:28:41.745  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@50f6ac94: startup date [Thu Aug 11 19:28:41 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    2016-08-11 19:28:44.766  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8a47c63] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:44.842  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b6b281] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:44.881  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f62a7725] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:45.115  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.cache-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:45.145  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:45.164  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GuavaCacheConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GuavaCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dc7afc2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:45.248  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManager' of type [class org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:45.252  INFO 30221 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.096  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/home/x/workspace/api/bin/schema.sql]
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.133  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/home/x/workspace/api/bin/schema.sql] in 37 ms.
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.161  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/home/x/workspace/api/bin/data.sql]
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.162  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/home/x/workspace/api/bin/data.sql] in 1 ms.
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.478  INFO 30221 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.513  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.667  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.669  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.671  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    2016-08-11 19:28:46.726  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    2016-08-11 19:28:47.147  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    2016-08-11 19:28:47.810  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
    2016-08-11 19:28:47.818  INFO 30221 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
    2016-08-11 19:28:47.870  INFO 30221 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.208  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.210  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/configuration/security]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.212  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.212  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/configuration/ui]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.218  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.219  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.632  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.633  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.634  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.635  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.636  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.637  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.638  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.639  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.639  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.642  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.645  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.646  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:49.647  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.073  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@50f6ac94: startup date [Thu Aug 11 19:28:41 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.137  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.137  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.188  INFO 30221 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.835  INFO 30221 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.859  INFO 30221 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
    2016-08-11 19:28:50.872  INFO 30221 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
    2016-08-11 19:28:51.280  INFO 30221 --- [           main] c.d.a.h.repository.FooRepositoryTest   : Started FooRepositoryTest in 10.174 seconds (JVM running for 10.888)
    2016-08-11 19:28:51.404  INFO 30221 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@50f6ac94: startup date [Thu Aug 11 19:28:41 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    2016-08-11 19:28:51.426  INFO 30221 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2016-08-11 19:28:51.426  INFO 30221 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
    2016-08-11 19:28:51.439  INFO 30221 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

My test `application-test.yml`:

```
    spring:
      datasource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem;MODE=MySQL
        username: sa
        password:
        initialize: true
      jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
          naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
          ddl-auto: none
          hbm2ddl:
            auto: none
        properties:
          hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
```

My test case:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public class FooRepositoryTest {

        @Autowired
        private FooRepository repository;

        @Test
        public void testFindOne() {
            Item foo = repository.findOne(4110L);
            assertThat(foo.getId()).isEqualTo(4110L);
        }
    }
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I moved to 1.3.3.RELEASE, maybe I will try version 1.4 again later.